# Online Bin Packing in 1D with Order Constraint

Tags: packing

I have a computer science problem that seems relatively simple.

1. We are given a number of 2D rectangles that we want to place next to each other on a 1D line (without rotating them). The 1D line has a certain finite length. The rectangles width is randomly and uniformly distributed between 0.1 - 10 units. The height is distributed as follows: 99% of elements are between 0.1 and 12 units high, 1% are between 12 and 200 units.
2. The rectangles come in one at a time, and they must be placed immediately. Once they have been placed, they cannot be moved. So we are looking for an online algorithm.
3. We want the rectangles to be "roughly sorted" by height. Of course, perfect sorting isn't possible because of (2).

The obvious algorithm would be to find the appropriate place on the line for each item, based on the known distribution of heights, and if that place is taken, find the closest spot that's free.

Is there a way to do better than that? "Better" in the sense of

1. Lower fragmentation so we don't run out of space too early
2. Getting as close as possible to a correct ordering

Have varients of this problem been studied, and if yes under what name?

Comment: What if a rectangle *can't* be placed (no free space wide enough left)?

Comment: That's the situation we want to avoid. The algorithm should place the rectangles in such a way that there is as little unused space as possible. Which means there are interesting trade-offs between placing rectangles at the optimum place in the ordering (creating spacing between this and other items), versus putting them right next to another one to minimise fragmentation. Essentially, this is a memory allocation problem.